# Unity3d files types. What are they for: .meta, .controller, .anim, .asset?

Tags: unity-game-engine

**Short Question:**

What is purpose of `.controler, .anim, .asset` file types in Unity project.

**Important note:**
The purpose of this questions is investigation of Unity3d project structure by it's files types.

I'm not asking how to prepare my project for git. I'm interested in purpose *and behavior* of files by their extension, looking for documentation as like as one in to **summary #1**.

**Introduction how do this question appears:**

I'm working with unity3d, and when I run a `git status` after sync I got a long list of modified/deleted files I did not touch. These files have next extentions: `*.meta, *.controller, *.anim, *.assets`

After long googling with different request I found good enough information only abut `*.meta` files and collisions that may happens when lose or duplicate `guid` in `*.meta` files. But other files extensions dose not represented so well in a google responses. And I able only guess what these kind of files do by their extension, but I prefer to definitely know it.

**Summary:**

Can you help me to find information about purpose, *structure and behavior* of files with next file extensions in Unity3d project.

1) What is `*.meta` file in Unity3d?

**answer#1:** *This file type contains data about assets that cannot be stored inside assets. Each asset has it own `*.meta` file.
https://blog.forrestthewoods.com/managing-meta-files-in-unity-713166ee3d30*

2) What is. `*.controller` file in Unity3d?

3) What is `*.anim` file in Unity3d?

4) What is `*.asset` file in Unit3d?

Comment: @TobiasTheel I'm not asking how to prepare my project for GIT. I'm asking about purpose of files in Unity3d project.

Comment: Let me rephrase my comments.

Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [How to Ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Just keep that in mind for future questions and people won't be unhappy, cause they can see no research effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) `*.meta` files store the settings of the files you have in your project.

2) It's [The Animator Controller Asset](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Animator.html).

3) It's [Animation Clip](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationClips.html).

4) It's Unity's own format that's used to store project settings or some resourses.

Comment: I would clarify to say the *import settings*, such as texture compression, model import scale, etc